# Late observable-array binding in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascriptserializer

My MVC razor view renders this markup:

```
function existingNamingsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            var initialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
            self.ExistingNamings = ko.observableArray(initialData);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new existingNamingsViewModel(), document.getElementById("namings-control"));
```

Into a correct JS-serialized code, with `initialData` variable being initialized as:

```
var initialData = [{"TypeName":"Orders","NameBlocks":["{intInc_G}","/","{intInc_D}","/02/-","{yy}"],"ParamBlocks":["2296","","1","",""]}];
```

The resulting html, after the ko bindings are applied, takes the form of an editable grid:
[image]

I need knockoutJS to automatically be able to update the view model whenever user changes data in those input fields. But since the view model was initialize from simple JSON object, `NameBlocks` and `ParamBlocks` are not `ko.observableArray`. I need them to be. How do I achieve this?

P.S. One idea is to do a more complex initialization where razor serializes only `Name`/`ParamBlocks` arrays, and `ExistingNamings` array is populated via javascript code manually, creating a custom Naming class object that has `Name`/`ParamBlocks` wrapped into `ko.observableArray`. But is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [mapping plug-in](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) available that should do the trick for you, though you may need to change the way the data is delivered.

The mapping plug-in provides a function that maps a JSON object to a view model:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Note though, in the documentation (linked to above), all properties within JSON objects are named.

The `initialData` you provided in your example contains arrays that are simply collections of values, rather than collections of named values.

Also, `initialData` is an array containing a single object.  If this scenario is always going to expect a single object, then this solution is easier.

Let's say that you're able to deliver `initialData` in the following format:

```
var initialData = {
    "TypeName":"Orders",
    "NameBlocks": [
        {"block":"{intInc_G}"},
        {"block":"/"},
        {"block":"{intInc_D}"},
        {"block":"/02/-"},
        {"block":"{yy}"}
    ],
    "ParamBlocks":[
        {"block":"2296"},
        {"block":""},
        {"block":"1"},
        {"block":""},
        {"block":""}
    ]
};
```

Then creating the view model would be as simple as the following:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

$(function() {
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel); 
});
```

Here's a fiddle I set up so you can see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/qUjLQ/

Hopefully, your solution will be as simple as a few data format changes and the use of the mapping plug-in.

Regardless, the mapping plug-in should send you in the right direction.

Comment: Tried it. But went ahead and used the "coded-models" approach I've mentioned in P.S. of my question, since mapping tool makes it very complicated to add functions to inner mapped elements.